# One webserver and two nodes - can I deploy same Spring app in both

Tags: jboss

I have installed jboss and created two servers ( 2 nodes) inside JBOSS_HOME.
One for the development and the other node is the Test server. If I deploy the same Spring MVC app on both nodes, will the singleton controller be shared among both Jboss nodes? or will the spring projects will work independently in each jboss nodes?

Comment: yes the they will run independtly, you can create cluster

Comment: But it's just 2 folders inside jboss_home and can run separately. Since both of the jboss nodes share the same JVM, according to the singleton scope definition, i suspect whether there will be a single instance of same controller which exists in application that deployed in both jboss instances.

Comment: not sure, but mostly each will have separate java process creating separate instance